# Schwarz-Christoffel transformation understanding

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I've been reading this explanation (see picture and text below) about the Schwarz-Christoffel mapping. I'm not really used to this sort of argument. My question is why are all terms constant in $(21.3)$ when $z$ is in between two points? It makes sense visually - but not sure why in terms of arguments. Thanks!

[image]

[http://www.mth.kcl.ac.uk/~shaww/web_page/books/complex/Chapter21Excerpt.pdf](http://www.mth.kcl.ac.uk/%7Eshaww/web_page/books/complex/Chapter21Excerpt.pdf)

Comment: they are constant because $z$ is real and moving on the real axis; let us suppose that $z\in (x_i,x_{i+1})$ then the arguments of the differences $z-x_j$ are fixed (=0 or $\pi$). Changes happen when $z=x_k$ for some $k$ and jumps across any such branch point $x_k$, as explained later in the text.

Comment: @Avitus Thank you, it just took a little while to sink in! Would happily accept as an answer if you wish to post it. :-)

Comment: The given link is dead. I have taken the liberty to suppress it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z\in\mathbb R$, with $z\in (x_i,x_{i+1})$ (open interval, in the text: "$z$ lies **strictly** between two of the $x_i$"), for some $i$. The arguments of the differences $z−x_j$ are all fixed, and equal to $0$ if $z>x_j$ or $\pi$ otherwise. Now, we arrive at a "jump" in the arguments exactly when the moving $z$ crosses any of the branching points $x_i$ or $x_{i+1}$ as explained in the text. As the above holds for all $i$'s, we arrive at the statement.